# Group table data into groups of N in Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array

I am looking for a way in Typescript to group data from table rows into all possible groups of N size?

For example:- Lets say I wanted to create groups of 3 (but this value can change) based on District (so all A's can be together, all B's etc), however I want to keep ALL the data.

So for A the groups would be as below yet keep ALL their meta data.  I am in looping hell and I'm thinking there must be something I'm missing!

| A Group |
| --- |
| John, Suzie, Areli |
| John, Suzie, Waylon |
| John, Suzie, Bentley |
| John, Areli, Waylon |
| John, Areli, Bentley |
| Suzie, Areli, Waylon |
| Suzie, Areli, Bentley |
| Areli, Waylon, Bentley |

Consider I have the following data:-

| Name | District | Favourite Color | Age Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | A | Red | 1 |
| Suzie | A | Green | 2 |
| Tom | B | Blue | 1 |
| Phillip | C | Blue | 1 |
| Tristen | C | Blue | 2 |
| Areli | A | Green | 2 |
| Cecilia | B | Blue | 2 |
| Elyse | D | Blue | 2 |
| Waylon | A | Green | 2 |
| Issac | B | Blue | 1 |
| Uriah | C | Green | 2 |
| Bentley | A | Green | 2 |
| Darian | B | Red | 1 |
| Haley | C | Red | 2 |
| Shaniya | D | Red | 1 |
| James | D | Green | 1 |

Comment: It’s this just a matter of filtering the data so only people belong to district A is picked, and then generate unique combinations of their names? There are already questions on StackOverflow that addresses generating combinations from an array.

Comment: Sadly no @Terry 

I also want people from District B, C, and D (the data will be hundreds of rows) and I need all the data. So I need X groups of N size with 4 columns per row. So multi dimensional array

Comment: You just essentially described what I said: just expend it from district A to all districts. You still need to generate unique combinations of length 3 from each array, grouped by district.